# In Rust, is there a difference in drop order for a Box:ed struct compared to a plain struct?

Tags: rust, scope, lifetime

The following code does not compile:

```
struct Ref<'a> {
    nbr: &'a u32,
}

fn func<'a>() {
    let nbr: u32 = 42;
    let _a_ref: Box<Ref<'a>> = Box::new(Ref { nbr: &nbr });
}

fn main() {
    func();
}
```

The compiler complains that `'nbr' does not live long enough` and that it is dropped at the end of `func()` while still borrowed. I have searched basically everywhere but I cannot understand why this error occurs. The variables are supposed to be dropped in reverse order compared to declaration, so the boxed `Ref` containing the reference should be dropped before `nbr` is dropped, right?

If I change `func()` into:

```
fn func<'a>() {
    let nbr: u32 = 42;
    let _a_ref = Ref { nbr: &nbr };
}
```

it builds just fine! So there is some difference to the required lifetime / scope for a boxed reference - but I cannot find any clear and simple explanation to this apparently basic question.

To make it even more confusing, I noted that if I state the type of `_a_ref` like this:

```
fn func<'a>() {
    let nbr: u32 = 42;
    let _a_ref: Ref<'a> = Ref { nbr: &nbr };
}
```

I once again get the `'nbr' does not live long enough` error.

Lastly, I played with the underscore, like this:

```
fn func<'a>() {
    let nbr: u32 = 42;
    let _a_ref: Ref<'_> = Ref { nbr: &nbr };
}
```

And now it builds just fine again! What is the difference between these 3 ways of using the non-boxed `Ref` struct? And how do they all compare to the boxed variant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Box` is not the problem here, `'a` is.

`&nbr` has the lifetime of `nbr`. But `'a` is a caller-chosen lifetime, which might (and even always will) be larger than the lifetime of `nbr`. So you cannot  assign `Ref<'nbr>` to `Ref<'a>`.

`Ref<'_>` means "let the compiler infer the lifetime", and is basically equivalent to not specifying the type at all.

Comment: I guess I have a hard time to understand exactly what the concept of lifetime in Rust exactly means and how it is applied by the compiler. I understand scope very well and that it is NOT the same. When you say that `'a` will be larger than the lifetime of `nbr`, what does that mean? And why does not the Box variant compile?

Comment: @MarcusJohansson The `Box` variant would compile if you used `Box<Ref<'_>>`, it doesn't compile because you tell the compiler to use `'a`, and since `'a` comes from the caller it lasts longer than the function.

Comment: Ahh, so by "caller-chosen" you mean that as a caller (or even just a function instantiating a struct and binding it to a variable), providing a reference and mentioning the lifetime `a` I will basically define this lifetime to include my full scope, which "slightly outlives" all variables in my scope as a caller? So the `&'a u32` in `Ref` therefore is required to be a valid reference even after the last variable in the scope is dropped.

But using `Ref<'_>` to allow the compiler to infer the lifetime in practice brings the applied lifetime closer to the scope / lexical life of `nbr`?

Comment: "Caller-chosen" means that whoever calls `func` will get to choose `'a`. The way you currently call it in `main`, `'a` starts just before `func` is called and ends just after it returns, which is indeed only "slightly" too long. But there's nothing preventing someone from calling it as `func::<'static>()`, which would require the reference to live forever.